# Flutter - Delegate Textfield in separate Class

Tags: dart, flutter

I want to use a separate class with a text field in Flutter.
The text field is already displayed and can be edited.
How can I pass the variable `_eingegebenerWert` to the class in which an object of this class was created?

**The code of the Text-Field Class:**

```
class eingabeTextbox extends StatelessWidget {
  final bool _nummerischeTastatur;
  final String _ueberschrift;
  final String _platzhalter;
  String _eingegebenerWert;

  eingabeTextbox(this._nummerischeTastatur, this._ueberschrift, this._platzhalter, this._eingegebenerWert);

  @override
  Widget build (BuildContext context){
    return new TextField(
        keyboardType: _nummerischeTastatur == true ? TextInputType.number : TextInputType.multiline,
        decoration: new InputDecoration(
            labelText: _ueberschrift,
            hintText: _platzhalter
        ),
        onChanged: (String str){
          _eingegebenerWert = str;
          print("neuer Wert:" + _eingegebenerWert);
        }
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the typedef `ValueChanged` to pass as parameter and get the value from another class, you are passing a method to receive the value:

```
    class eingabeTextbox extends StatelessWidget {
      final bool _nummerischeTastatur;
      final String _ueberschrift;
      final String _platzhalter;
      ValueChanged<String> eingegebenerWert;

      eingabeTextbox(this._nummerischeTastatur, this._ueberschrift, this._platzhalter, this.eingegebenerWert);

      @override
      Widget build (BuildContext context){
        return new TextField(
            keyboardType: _nummerischeTastatur == true ? TextInputType.number : TextInputType.multiline,
            decoration: new InputDecoration(
                labelText: _ueberschrift,
                hintText: _platzhalter
            ),
            onChanged: eingegebenerWert
        );
      }
    }
```

Call from another class

```
    @override
      Widget build (BuildContext context){
        return new eingabeTextbox(
            ...
            eingegebenerWert: (String str){
              print("neuer Wert:" + str);
            }
        );
      }
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This works very well. A small change was still required when calling: new eingabeTextbox(false, "Beschreibung", "010A", (String str){print("neuer Wert:" + str);}), Big THX :)